# the intégral is convergent

Tags: integration

find all positive numbers a;b such that the intégral

\begin{array}{l}
 \int\limits_b^{ + \infty } {f(x)dx} \quad {\rm } \\ 
 f(x) = \sqrt {\sqrt {x + a}  - \sqrt x }  - \sqrt {\sqrt x  - \sqrt {x - b} }  \\ 
  \Rightarrow f(x) = \frac{{\sqrt {x + a}  - \sqrt x  - \left( {\sqrt x  - \sqrt {x - b} } \right)}}{{\sqrt {\sqrt {x + a}  - \sqrt x }  + \sqrt {\sqrt x  - \sqrt {x - b} } }} \\ 
  \Rightarrow f(x) = \frac{{\sqrt {x + a}  - \sqrt x }}{{\sqrt {\sqrt {x + a}  - \sqrt x }  + \sqrt {\sqrt x  - \sqrt {x - b} } }} - \frac{{\sqrt x  - \sqrt {x - b} }}{{\sqrt {\sqrt {x + a}  - \sqrt x }  + \sqrt {\sqrt x  - \sqrt {x - b} } }} \\ 
  \Rightarrow f(x) = g(x) - h(x) \\ 
 g(x) = \frac{a}{{\left( {\sqrt {x + a}  + \sqrt x } \right)\left( {\sqrt {\sqrt {x + a}  - \sqrt x }  + \sqrt {\sqrt x  - \sqrt {x - b} } } \right)}} \\ 
 h(x) = \frac{b}{{\left( {\sqrt x  + \sqrt {x - b} } \right)\left( {\sqrt {\sqrt {x + a}  - \sqrt x }  + \sqrt {\sqrt x  - \sqrt {x - b} } } \right)}} \\ 
 \end{array}
help me please you to complete the exercise

intégral  h and intégral g is convergents? why?

thank you in advance

Comment: Please edit so there's a question in the body of your question.

Comment: What's the point of $g$ and $h$ in this question?